# Android "cl cannot be resolved to a variable" error

Tags: android

I have a problem with AIDL file of android. I downloaded a sample project from internet, I saw in the code, they have an AIDL file. I don't know what this file is and I do some research and write some code.

After create an AIDL file, I declare a method like this

```
interface IRemoteService{
  Map onClick(in int id, in Map state);
}
```

Then Eclipse will auto generate a file `IRemoteService.java` and also return error:

```
cl cannot be resolved to a variable
```

Did I do something wrong?

**Edit**
This is IRemoteService.java which auto generated.

```
/*
 * This file is auto-generated.  DO NOT MODIFY.
 * Original file: /home/nampham/Data/works/workspace/MapAidl/src/nampham/mapaidl/IRemoteService.aidl
 */
package nampham.mapaidl;
public interface IRemoteService extends android.os.IInterface
{
/** Local-side IPC implementation stub class. */
public static abstract class Stub extends android.os.Binder implements nampham.mapaidl.IRemoteService
{
private static final java.lang.String DESCRIPTOR = "nampham.mapaidl.IRemoteService";
/** Construct the stub at attach it to the interface. */
public Stub()
{
this.attachInterface(this, DESCRIPTOR);
}
/**
 * Cast an IBinder object into an nampham.mapaidl.IRemoteService interface,
 * generating a proxy if needed.
 */
public static nampham.mapaidl.IRemoteService asInterface(android.os.IBinder obj)
{
if ((obj==null)) {
return null;
}
android.os.IInterface iin = (android.os.IInterface)obj.queryLocalInterface(DESCRIPTOR);
if (((iin!=null)&&(iin instanceof nampham.mapaidl.IRemoteService))) {
return ((nampham.mapaidl.IRemoteService)iin);
}
return new nampham.mapaidl.IRemoteService.Stub.Proxy(obj);
}
public android.os.IBinder asBinder()
{
return this;
}
@Override public boolean onTransact(int code, android.os.Parcel data, android.os.Parcel reply, int flags) throws android.os.RemoteException
{
switch (code)
{
case INTERFACE_TRANSACTION:
{
reply.writeString(DESCRIPTOR);
return true;
}
case TRANSACTION_click:
{
data.enforceInterface(DESCRIPTOR);
int _arg0;
_arg0 = data.readInt();
java.util.Map _arg1;
java.lang.ClassLoader cl = (java.lang.ClassLoader)this.getClass().getClassLoader();
_arg1 = data.readHashMap(cl);
java.util.Map _result = this.click(_arg0, _arg1);
reply.writeNoException();
reply.writeMap(_result);
return true;
}
}
return super.onTransact(code, data, reply, flags);
}
private static class Proxy implements nampham.mapaidl.IRemoteService
{
private android.os.IBinder mRemote;
Proxy(android.os.IBinder remote)
{
mRemote = remote;
}
public android.os.IBinder asBinder()
{
return mRemote;
}
public java.lang.String getInterfaceDescriptor()
{
return DESCRIPTOR;
}
public java.util.Map click(int id, java.util.Map state) throws android.os.RemoteException
{
android.os.Parcel _data = android.os.Parcel.obtain();
android.os.Parcel _reply = android.os.Parcel.obtain();
java.util.Map _result;
try {
_data.writeInterfaceToken(DESCRIPTOR);
_data.writeInt(id);
_data.writeMap(state);
mRemote.transact(Stub.TRANSACTION_click, _data, _reply, 0);
_reply.readException();
_result = _reply.readHashMap(cl);  `<<< This line return error`
}
finally {
_reply.recycle();
_data.recycle();
}
return _result;
}
}
static final int TRANSACTION_click = (android.os.IBinder.FIRST_CALL_TRANSACTION + 0);
}
public java.util.Map click(int id, java.util.Map state) throws android.os.RemoteException;
}
```

Thanks in advance.

Comment: What is `aidl file`? And could you post the whole trace

Comment: Hi, please have a look to this page: [Android Interface Definition Language (AIDL)](http://developer.android.com/guide/components/aidl.html)
You will know what aidl file is.

Comment: Use CAPS! Now post the full trace.

Comment: Sorry, I don't know what CAPS is. you want to know how I did and what I receive from Eclipse, right?

Comment: CAPS: `aidl -> AIDL` :). Ans yes, post the error log you recieve from Eclipse.

Comment: What I receive from Eclipse is "cl cannot be resolved to a variable". Only this message. And this message returned after Eclipse generate IRemoteService.java file.

Comment: You mean this is a `line error`? Is `cl` a variable name?

Comment: I don't know about 'cl', I only create an IRemoteService.aidl file and declare a method, then I save it. Eclipse auto generate IRemoteService.java and return the error message above. I don't know why it return error. I didn't edit anything in IRemoteService.java file.

Comment: can you post the autogenerated java file too

Comment: I just post the auto generated java file above.

Answer (score 0):

The problem is in:

```
_result = _reply.readHashMap(cl);
```

Where `cl can't be resolved to a variable` because `cl` is **defined locally** in `onTransact()`:

```
java.lang.ClassLoader cl = (java.lang.ClassLoader)this.getClass().getClassLoader();
```

I don't know if `auto-generated code` means that *it shouldn't be modified* or *it can't be modified*. However, what I can tell you is this error will never go away unless you edited the code and:

- Add another `cl` definition before the error line:

  ```
  java.lang.ClassLoader cl = (java.lang.ClassLoader)this.getClass().getClassLoader();
  _result = _reply.readHashMap(cl);
  ```

Comment: Thank you for you time.
I have added the line above before the error line as you said, but Eclipse return error after I save file. The error is "IRemoteService.java was modified manually! Reverting to generated version!".

Comment: @NamPham Sorry. I can't think of anything else.